# Currently Using MySQL, Looking at DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I currently use MySQL, after looking into Document DB it seems like it may be a good move. I do a TON (95%) of querying for single records. As my database gets larger, the time its taking to do this seems to be getting slower. Both reading and writing. I'm curious based on the (simplified) scheme below if it could be a good move to a DocumentDB, and what the layout would be for said schema (i'm a bit new to documentDB)

**User**
UserID
Username
CreatedDate

**Tank**
TankID
UserID REF User.UserID
TankName
Awards

**Map**
MapID
MapName
MapFIle

**MapData**
MapID REF Map.MapID
TankID REF Tank.TankID
Rank
Color
TimePlayed
Equipment

Everytime a player joins, the data from Tank,MapaData is Queried to gather a full tank object. Every time they die, win an award, kill somebody, or exit the game, the data is then written back out to tank,and mapdata.

The website queries the User table for login, which stores the username and a hash of the password. Once logged in the users are able to modify/delete/create new tanks on the website, which inserts records into the tank/mapdata tables.

The website also stores Top 25 in the World, t25 in map, t25 for each color, t25 for each color for each map.

That's about the only query patterns I can think of at this moment.

Comment: The schema design would heavily depend on your query patterns. An example, if your user changes on a regular basis it is good to keep it in its on collection. If not, you could put it as a subdocument in your **Tank** document. Can you explain your typical query patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided information you have the choice of several schema designs (with JSON as examples). I've made some assumptions, such as that more than one tank can be on one map and map data is only linked to a single map. You have to tweak it for your needs. I also try to provide some advantages and disadvantages of every solution.

**Option #1 (Single collection)**

This should be the easiest, but not the best solution. Here you put everything into one document with extreme "denormalization".

```
{
  "mapname": "map1",
  "mapfile": "mapfile1",
  "data": {
    "rank": "rank1",
    "color": "color1",
    ...
    "tanks": [
      {
        "name": "tank1",
        ...
        "user": {
          "name": "user1",
          ...
        }
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This solution works best when you do a lot of writes, rare updates and reads where you want to get all information together. On the other side it has a lot of disadvantages, such as storing user information directly into your application data (an example would be the password hash).

**Option #2 (Two collections)**

Put your user data into one collection and the other data into a second collection.

*User collection*

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "passwordhash",
  ...
}
```

*Data collection*

```
{
  "mapname": "map1",
  "mapfile": "mapfile1",
  "data": {
    "rank": "rank1",
    "color": "color1",
    ...
    "tanks": [
      {
        "name": "tank1",
        ...
        "user": userId
        }
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This option is a lot better than the first one. First you don't want to have sensitive user data (such as the hash of the password) in a collection with your other data. Also this works better for reads of the user object, because you just retrieve the information you need without skipping a lot of not needed fields. A disadvantage is that heavy write operations on the tank object can become a problem.

**Option #3 (Three collections)**

The next step could be to move the tanks out of the data collection into their own collection.

*User collection*

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "passwordhash",
  ...
}
```

*Tank collection*

```
{
  "name": "tank1",
  ...
  "user": userId
}
```

*Data collection*

```
{
  "mapname": "map1",
  "mapfile": "mapfile1",
  "data": {
    "rank": "rank1",
    "color": "color1",
    ...
    "tanks": [
      idOfTank1,
      idOfTank2,
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

This works best for a lot of writes of single objects, such as the tanks, and reading tanks from their collection. This solution has its problems when reading a lot of data together, for example if you want to get a map and all the tanks in that map. In that case you have to resolve the dependencies of the tanks and the map data.

**Summary**

As seen, schema design is not easy in a document-oriented database. This is the reason why I asked for the query patterns. To come up with a good design you have to know most of the query patterns in advance. To get started, you should create a simple prototype with a design you think makes sense and test your query patterns with some test data. If that works, you can make minor changes to get even better performance. If not, rethink your query patterns and how a better design could look like. Keep in mind that you don't need a full-blown application for that. Most of that can be tested before a single line of code is written, for example with the administration shell of MongoDB or a simple console application in the case of DocumentDB.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fantastic description. This makes a lot of sense to me. In my case, very rarely is the tank object written to, but more often i'm writing to MapData(since it changes very frequently.)